# How to sort by letters *and* numbers in prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have a list in Prolog like the following:

```
[(b,y,3),(p,z,1),(p,y,3),(b,y,2),(p,z,2),(p,x,3),...]
```

where the first element of the first tuple is in `[b,p]`, the second is in `[x,y,z]`, and the third is in `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`.

How do I sort this list of tuples so that the above sample of list becomes:

```
[(b,y,2),(b,y,3),(p,x,3),(p,y,3),(p,z,1),(p,z,2),...]
```

that is, b comes before p, x before y and z and the numbers are sorted.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort preserving duplicate entries in SICStus and many other Prologs use `keysort/2`:

```
msort(Keys, KeysS) :-
   keys_pairs(Keys, Pairs), % pairs_keys(Pairs, Keys)
   keysort(Pairs, PairsS),
   pairs_keys(PairsS, KeysS).

keys_pairs([], []).
keys_pairs([K|Ks], [K-_|Ps]) :-
   keys_pairs(Ks, Ps).

pairs_keys([], []).
pairs_keys([K-_|Ps],[K|Ks]) :-
   pairs_keys(Ps, Ks).
```

SICStus and many other Prologs need both `keys_pairs/2` and `pairs_keys/2` for an efficient mapping.

Answer (score 3):

Use `apropos`

```
apropos( sort ).
```

It shows that there are some built-in predicates helps you with your problem - `sort` with removing duplicates and `msort` without removing duplicates.

```
?- sort( [(b,y,3),(p,z,1),(p,y,3),(b,y,2),(p,z,2),(p,x,3)], X).
X = [ (b, y, 2), (b, y, 3), (p, x, 3), (p, y, 3), (p, z, 1), (p, z, 2)].

?- msort( [(b,y,3),(p,z,1),(p,y,3),(b,y,2),(p,z,2),(p,x,3)], X).
X = [ (b, y, 2), (b, y, 3), (p, x, 3), (p, y, 3), (p, z, 1), (p, z, 2)].
```

Comment: I dunno. Do you need an answer without any built-in predicates?

Comment: SICStus doesn't have `msort/2` - see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

With SWI-Prolog you can use predsort(+Pred, +List, -Sorted) and define your own way to sort tuples (but msort, does yhe job very well without removing duplicates).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use sort(+List, -Sorted). But be aware that sort/2 removes duplicate entries.

http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2